# What is the difference between passing data via ViewData.Model and View's argument?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am very new to asp.net mvc. It might be a "childish" question. :-)

We can pass data from within a controller using two methods (among others of course) as follows:

```
ViewData.Model=obj;
return View();
```

or

```
return View(obj);
```

What is the pros and cons for each approach?

Comment: From my understanding, there is no difference.

Comment: But really, use the 2nd option.  It is considerably more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both snippets are the same, the first option passed directly to the object model while the second is passed as a parameter to the View but eventually will be passed to the object model.

If you look into the `View()` method, you can see the first snippet called inside.

```
protected internal ViewResult View(object model) {
    return View(null, null, model);
}

protected internal virtual ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model) {
    if (model != null) {
        ViewData.Model = model;
    }

    ....
}
```

Therefore both are the same but the first is a direct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Technically I don't think there is any difference...

I prefer to use the second approach as to me it just "feels" nicer...